# Existence of linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

My book proves the following theorems:

> Three distinct points $A,B,C$ are collinear if and only if there exist 3 numbers, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, all different from zero, such that $$\lambda_1 \boldsymbol a +\lambda_2 \boldsymbol b +\lambda_3 \boldsymbol c =0,\space \space \space \space \space \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0$$ 
>   If no three of the points of $A,B,C,D$ are collinear, they will be coplanar if and only if there exist 4 numbers, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$, different from zero, such that $$\lambda_1 \boldsymbol a +\lambda_2 \boldsymbol b +\lambda_3 \boldsymbol c +\lambda_4 \boldsymbol d=0,\space \space \space \space \space \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=0$$

A logical extension of this is to ask the following:

Given that no four points of A,B,C,D,E are coplanar, will there always exist 5 numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4,\lambda_5$ sll different from zero, such that 
$$\lambda_1 \boldsymbol a +\lambda_2 \boldsymbol b +\lambda_3 \boldsymbol c +\lambda_4 \boldsymbol d+\lambda_5 \boldsymbol e=0,\space \space \space \space \space \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4+\lambda_5=0  $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that these points lie in (3 dimensional) space, then this is true. Indeed, if we consider the four-dimensional vector space $V=\mathbb R^4$ composed of vectors $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4)$ with an implied $\lambda_5=-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4),$ the map $\phi:V\to \mathbb R^3$ sending $$\lambda\to\lambda_1\boldsymbol a+\lambda_2\boldsymbol b+\lambda_3\boldsymbol c+\lambda_4\boldsymbol d+\lambda_5\boldsymbol e$$ must have kernel dimension at least $1$.

If, however, the points lie in $4$ or higher dimensions, then your statement does not hold, for the same reason the analogous statements do not hold in lower dimensions.